# How to return data from inside Promise, reduce, format?

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck on trying to make this test pass for awhile. I want it to return an array of 3 objects of mockExpectedResult

Step 1: Reduce scheduled operations array (omit items that don't have path). This should return array of strings of InventoryItemPath

Step 2: Reduce over InventoryItemPath array (freeRewardsInventory), make async call to service (getItem is a mock of this async GET request) which returns Promise.

Step 3: Reducer over freeRewardsRaw Promises, format into mockExpectedResult

Step 4: Return output (Array of mockExpectedResults)

I think my main issue is that I'm not awaiting all of these promises (missing one await maybe?)

Thanks for helping.

```
const mockScheduledOperation = {
    Ranks: [{
            FreeRewards: {
                InventoryRewards: [{
                    InventoryItemPath: 'Inventory/Armor/Visors/012-001-reach-c09fa0b7.json',
                }, ],
            },
        },
        {
            FreeRewards: {
                InventoryRewards: [{
                    InventoryItemPath: 'Inventory/Armor/Visors/012-001-reach-c09fa0b7.json',
                }, ],
            },
        },
        {
            FreeRewards: {
                InventoryRewards: [{
                    InventoryItemPath: 'Inventory/Armor/Visors/012-001-reach-c09fa0b7.json',
                }, ],
            },
        }
    ]
};

const getAllRewards = async () => {
    const freeRewardsInventory = mockScheduledOperation.Ranks.reduce(
        (agg, rank) => {
            if (rank.FreeRewards.InventoryRewards.length > 0) {
                const rewardList = rank.FreeRewards.InventoryRewards.reduce(
                    (agg, reward) => {
                        if (reward.InventoryItemPath) {
                            agg = reward.InventoryItemPath;
                        }
                        return agg;
                    },
                    ''
                );
                agg.push(rewardList);
            }
            return agg;
        },
        []
    );

    const getItem = async (rewardPath: string) => mockReturnedItem;

    const freeRewardsRaw = freeRewardsInventory.reduce < [] > (
        async (agg, rewardPath) => {
                const promise = await getItem(rewardPath);
                agg.push(promise);
                return agg;
            },
            []
    );

    const formattedRewards = await Promise.all(freeRewardsRaw).then(
        (response) => {
            response.reduce < ProgressionRewards[] > ((agg, res) => {
                const formattedReward: ProgressionRewards = {
                    // free = unlocked, paid = locked
                    locked: false,
                    level: null,
                    difficulty: res.CommonData.Quality || null,
                    date: res.CommonData.DateReleased.ISO8601Date || null,
                    rewardAttachments: [{
                        image: res.CommonData.DisplayPath.Media.MediaUrl.Path || null,
                        title: res.CommonData.Title.value || null,
                        description: res.CommonData.Description.value || null,
                        type: res.CommonData.Type || null,
                        released: null,
                        manufacturer: null,
                        howUnlock: null,
                    }, ],
                };
                agg.push(formattedReward);
                return agg;
            }, []);
        }
    );

    return formattedRewards;
};

const mockExpectedResult: ProgressionRewards = {
    locked: false,
    level: null,
    difficulty: ChallengeLevel.Easy,
    date: '',
    rewardAttachments: [{
        image: 'media-image-path',
        title: 'MIA',
        description: 'reach-mia',
        type: 'ArmorVisor',
        released: null,
        manufacturer: null,
        howUnlock: null,
    }, ],
};

fit('free rewards to return an array of rewards', async () => {
    const awards: ProgressionRewards = await getAllRewards();

    expect(awards).toBe([
        mockExpectedResult,
        mockExpectedResult,
        mockExpectedResult,
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `reduce`s, when these can be simply replaced by `map`s and `filter`s?

Comment: The same issue would exist - namely attempting to return a value from within a Promise.

Comment: @smtaha512 not all ranks have InventoryItemPath. I should probably use a filter though, correct

Comment: @RandyCasburn correct. seems like the issue is that it's being returned before all the promises come back. do you know how to not only dig out the data from the promise, but have the return await all of the promises?

Comment: I just would not take this approach - and I hope you see why. If code comprehension is so difficult that it slows your productivity - then simplify, simplify, simplify. You've way overcomplicated this with the use of `.reduce()` when in most instances you are returning an array containing the iterates. So @smtaha512 is correct. But, you should fall all the way back to using simple `for()` loops. I think you'll be amazed at how easy this actually is when taking that approach. Hope that helps.

Comment: @RandyCasburn will do, thanks. i'll swap these reduces for maps with conditionals, see if i can create more clarity then see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to simplify your code and the issue in the `reduce`. I have replace the `reduce`s with `filter`s and `map`s. Please check this out and let me know if this would help.

```
const mockScheduledOperation = {
    Ranks: [{
            FreeRewards: {
                InventoryRewards: [{
                    InventoryItemPath: 'Inventory/Armor/Visors/012-001-reach-c09fa0b7.json',
                }, ],
            },
        },
        {
            FreeRewards: {
                InventoryRewards: [{
                    InventoryItemPath: 'Inventory/Armor/Visors/012-001-reach-c09fa0b7.json',
                }, ],
            },
        },
        {
            FreeRewards: {
                InventoryRewards: [{
                    InventoryItemPath: 'Inventory/Armor/Visors/012-001-reach-c09fa0b7.json',
                }, ],
            },
        }
    ]
};
    
const getAllRewards = async () => {
    
    const freeRewardsInventory = 
        ([] as string[])
        // converting multi-dimensional array into uni-dimensional
        .concat(
            ...mockScheduledOperation.Ranks
            .filter(rank => rank.FreeRewards.InventoryRewards.length)
            .map(rank => (
                rank.FreeRewards.InventoryRewards
                    // removing all falsy values
                    .filter(Boolean)
                    .map(item => item.InventoryItemPath)
            )
        )
    );

    const getItem = (rewardPath: string) => mockReturnedItem;


    const freeRewardsRaw = await Promise.all(freeRewardsInventory.map(rewardPath => getItem(rewardPath)))

    const formattedRewards = freeRewardsRaw
        .map < ProgressionRewards[] > ((res) => {
                const formattedReward: ProgressionRewards = {
                    // free = unlocked, paid = locked
                    locked: false,
                    level: null,
                    difficulty: res.CommonData.Quality || null,
                    date: res.CommonData.DateReleased.ISO8601Date || null,
                    rewardAttachments: [{
                        image: res.CommonData.DisplayPath.Media.MediaUrl.Path || null,
                        title: res.CommonData.Title.value || null,
                        description: res.CommonData.Description.value || null,
                        type: res.CommonData.Type || null,
                        released: null,
                        manufacturer: null,
                        howUnlock: null,
                    }, ],
                };
                return formattedReward;
            }, []);
        }
    );

    return formattedRewards;
};
```

Comment: Huge help!!! Solves everything, thanks so much! So the main issue was mapping over the Promise all on the freeRewardsRaw line I see (and replacing reduce with filter)

Comment: Yes. Actually what I think, `reduce` is a very powerful tool but should be used with caution. Since it can also make the code hard to debug which could be simpler with other methods.